# What property does Gauss-Bonnet theorem indicate for a function defined on a 2D Riemannian surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If I have a function defined on a 2D Riemannian surface, what can Gauss-Bonnet theorem tell me about the property of this function? I just want to get a picture of this theorem in my mind. An example would be better.

Comment: What kind's of properties are you looking for?

Comment: I am trying to connect the topological property of such a function with some meaningful quantity that can be probed physically. So suppose I have a physical quantity (such as electric charge or current) defined by such a function, does its topological property have a relationship with conservation laws of physics?